# Tense simplification: use would, could, might, should to express possibility, uncertainty, etc. in the present

Tags: grammar, tense, sequence-of-tenses, auxiliary

The book *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan says:
The tense in the subordinate clause tends to be simplified.

He gives some examples:

> (a) If I (would have) had lots of money, I would give some to anybody who (would ask) asked for it.

> (b) In a perfect world, you would be able to say exactly what you (would think) thought.

> (c) I would always try to help anybody who was in trouble, whether I knew them or not.

And since *Would* has the meaning of *will* just with a softer tone, it got me thinking:
What tense should I use when I use *would* to talk about the present and future, but with doubt, uncertainty, or possibility?

Examples I came up with:

> (1) I would go to the park with her if she **invites/invited** me.
> =>I want to use "would" to express uncertainty in my willingness to go to the park.

> (2) This thing is weird. I would think Tom **is/was** able to explain.
> =>I want to use "would" to express uncertainty in my thinking.

> (3) I have this extra money on me. I would give it to friends who **ask/asked** for it.
> =>I want to use "would" to express uncertainty or possibility of giving money.

Do they have anything to do with tense simplification?
If not, does it mean that I can use tenses depending on what I try to say?

By *depending on what I try to say*, I mean like:

> I can use *invites* in (1) because it happens in the future.

> I can use "Tom is able to explain" in (2) because it happens in the future.

> And I can use either one of the phrases down below:

> > (4)use ***friends who asked for it*** to mean in the past, there were friends of mine that asked for money from me

> > (5)use ***friends who ask for it*** to mean the friends that might or will ask me for money in the future

Finally, how about *could, might, should*; I remember they can also be used to express uncertainty, doubt, etc. Do they follow the same rules?

Comment: I think "might" might work for the first 3 sentences: *"I might go to the park with her if she invites me."*, *"This thing is weird. I think Tom might explain it."*, and *"I have this extra money on me. I might give it to friends who ask for it."*

Answer (score 0):

I'll give a partial answer, in case it helps.  It will take the form of the full expansions that I think your author is simplifying from.  It is an interesting point; I rarely think about all the freedom we have to shorten these things.

But in general, I'll point out that all these words - should, would, will, can, might, may - give use quite a bit of freedom... a lot of experience listening and taking part in conversations will help build your confidence with what to do and when.

Here are my ideas on the full versions of these:

(a) If I had lots o f money, I would give some to anybody who asked for it.

> *Were I to have / If I were to have* lots of money, I would give some to anybody who asked for it.

(b) In a perfect world, you would be able to say exactly what you thought.

> *Were we to live in a perfect world / If this were to be a perfect world*, you would be able to say exactly what you thought.

(c) I would always try to help anybody who was in trouble, whether I knew them or no

> I would always try to help anybody who was in trouble, whether it were true that I knew them or not

> whether it were to be the case that I knew them or not

> were I to know them or not *(I guess the best, as it is shorter and I think gets it done)*

Hopefully I am getting this right; as I say, it's been awhile since I noticed it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sorry, I have added some additional information to my question because my questions were not very clear. The original sentences the author gives are focused on simplifying "would + verb" to "past tense verb". And I don't know whether it is also a rule that applies when I want to use "would", "could", "might" to express present or future possibility or want to use them as softer "will", "can", and "may".

Comment: It is somewhat difficult to speak generally about the differences, and the veracity/strength, etc.  But I feel like you are on your way to understanding the situation.  I think many examples is a good path to full confidence.  Often the deciding factor in language is the actual set of ideas that we need to be able to express - what things might a person be trying to tell you?  What phrases can we generate?  Does one sound more like it means what I want than what I don't?  And sometimes, we compromise by saying something much shorter, and then maybe add more, to patch things up.

Comment: a small thing I could note is that, at least to me, "might" and "may" are very often indistinguishable

Comment: and historically, at least, I think "would" is really the same word as "willed", in a sense.. but "will" is often quite stronger nowadays